# Detecting new PairCreated events on Polygon blockchain with Web3 and Python

Tags: python, blockchain, polygon, binance-smart-chain, web3py

I'm trying to make a program that continuously detects new tokens on the polygon blockchain as soon as liquidity has been added (PairCreated event). Below is the main section of the code.

I am using quickSwap factory address (0x5757371414417b8C6CAad45bAeF941aBc7d3Ab32) as that seems to be the pancakeswap equivalent for polygon network (theres references in the code for pancakeswap, I mean quickswap). Also using the same ABI as BSC which seems to be fine.

I have managed to get this working fine on the binance smart chain but nothing is ever detected when running with polygon. I however read somewhere that apparently Polygon does not support the current method.

Could anyone shed some light on what needs to be done to get this working?
Thanks!

```
#import web3 and all other modules

web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(bscNode))

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapFactoryAddress, abi=listeningABI)

def foundToken(event):
    jsonEventContents = json.loads(Web3.toJSON(event))
    #process token data etc
        

        
async def tokenLoop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        try:
            for PairCreated in event_filter.get_new_entries():
                foundToken(PairCreated)
            await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)
        except:
            pass
            
            
def listenForTokens():
    event_filter = contract.events.PairCreated.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                tokenLoop(event_filter, 2)))       
                 
    finally:
        listenForTokens()


listenForTokens()
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```py
pair_created_event = contract.events.PairCreated()
event_filter = pair_created_event.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
entries = event_filter.get_new_entries()
print(entries)
```

You need to call the `PairCreated` event instead of just using the reference.

Also please check the contract address you are using. For PancakeSwap you can find the official ones in their documentation: https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/smart-contracts#main-contracts